# Angular 7 FormControlName gives console error

Tags: angular, forms, typescript

I have a reactive form on my webpage, but it gives an error that looks like this:

> ERROR Error: formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup
>   directive.  You'll want to add a formGroup
>          directive and pass it an existing FormGroup instance (you can create one in your class).

I don't understand why i am getting this error because i have a formGroup instance.

This is my HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="singleRecipientForm">
    <textarea #textInput placeholder="user e-mail" formControlName="email"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" (click)="sendMailTextInput(textInput.value)">Send invite </button>
</form
```

And my typescript looks like this:

```
singleRecipientForm: FormGroup;

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.singleRecipientForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', [Validators.required]],
    });
}
```

I have no clue to why this error is appearing.

Comment: Try moving your `ngOnInit` code into your constructor, or add a `*ngIf="singleRecipientForm"` in your form tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not closed the form tag correctly ().

```
 <form [formGroup]="singleRecipientForm">
        <textarea #textInput placeholder="user e-mail" formControlName="email"></textarea>
        <button type="submit" (click)="sendMailTextInput(textInput.value)">Send invite </button>
    </form>
```

If that's not the issue, please check you have imported the reactiveformsmodule in your module.ts

Answer (score 1):

Apart the missing tag, when you are using Reactive forms, you do not need template ref to get input value.

```
singleRecipientForm: FormGroup;

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit() {
this._buildForm();

}
private _buildForm(): void {
        this.singleRecipientForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: New FromControl('', Validators.required)
    });
}
public sendMailTextInput(): any {
console.log(this.singleRecipientForm.value)
}
```

and your html would be `(click)="sendMailTextInput()"` and then do what ever you want with the text input.
Reactive Forms come with number of methods that can ease your development (valueChanges(), ...)

Comment: Thanks for the extra explanation